# How use CSS to make a child image use percentage with of parent's parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a child element that is an image. It's floated next to another div inside a parent. I want the image's width to be a percentage of the parent's parent. However, its parent does not have a set width to work off (because the text in the other child div can vary). Is there a way to still use % to set the image's width relative to the grandparent?

```
<div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
        <!-- I want this to be 30% the width of grandparent -->
        <img class="myImage" src="someimage.jpg" />

        <div class="text">Some text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent would simply use `overflow: hidden;` and grandparent has a width of `width: 100%;` and the two children are both `float: left;`.

**EDIT:** The parent div must shrink to the child divs so it doesn't run over sibling divs. That's why it has no width but uses `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the parent div to 100% it should take the width of the grandparent. That will allow you to properly use 30% on your image.

```
.grandparent {
  width: 400px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.myImage {
  width: 30%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vx5we080/)

Comment: I can't as I need the parent div to shrink to the contents (sorry I didn't mention that, I just put that in my post as an edit) so it doesn't run over other siblings.

Comment: Can you create a quick fiddle where siblings are involved?

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes

Comment: This isn't perfect, but here's a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/qpact3pe/ (I set the image's height to 100% for now just so you could see the image)